# Windowing / grouping by date with key in apache beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to filter my data with Apache Beam so that each User Agent/hash combination counts once per day (i.e. fixed 24 hour period starting at midnight UTC)

My input table has the following columns: date (timestamp), user_agent, hash, url

From reading the docs i think that i need to use windowing but maybe it is not the best approach

This is what i have so far but i am stuck on how to make the windowing work with a specific key and how to actually specific which field has the timestamp in it

```
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


def is_valid(element):
    # logic
    return True


class AddDevicesId(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        element['device'] = "device"
        yield element


def run(
        input_table: str,
        output_table: str,
        window_offset: int = 0,
        beam_args: list[str] = None,
) -> None:
    """Build and run the pipeline."""
    options = PipelineOptions(beam_args, save_main_session=True,
                              project="-393506", temp_location="gs://prod/tmp/")

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        rows = p | 'ReadLogs' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(method="DIRECT_READ", table=input_table,
                                                          gcs_location="gs://prod/tmp")

        mapped_data = rows | 'Add device id' >> beam.ParDo(AddDevicesId())

        filtered_data = mapped_data | 'Filter data' >> beam.Filter(
            lambda x: is_valid(x))

        # Use windowing to count User Agent/hash combinations once per day
        windowed_data = filtered_data | 'Windowing' >> beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.FixedWindows(24 * 60 * 60),  # 24-hour window
            accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
        )

        windowed_data | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=output_table,
            schema={'fields': [
                {'name': 'date', 'type': 'TIMESTAMP', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
                {'name': 'device', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
                {'name': 'user_agent', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
                {'name': 'url', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]},

            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            custom_gcs_temp_location="gs://prod/write-tmp",
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_table",
        help="Input BigQuery table for results specified as: "
             "PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE.",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table",
        help="Output BigQuery table for results specified as: "
             "PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE.",
    )

    args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run(
        input_table=args.input_table,
        output_table=args.output_table,
        beam_args=beam_args,
    )
```